# HTTP - 500 org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed;

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'm using :

1. Apache Tomcat 6.0.20
2. Spring 3.x

I want to create simple "Hello World !!!" on my index page. Unfortunately, I get the following error:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/Config
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:820)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:716)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

this is my controller called **IndexController.java**

```
package com.dprima.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class IndexController {
    @RequestMapping("/index")
    public ModelAndView index(){
        String message = "Hello World !!!";
        return new ModelAndView("index","hello",message);
    }
}
```

my **web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>passion</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

      <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.php</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>

      <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
      </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

my **dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
 ...
        <context:component-scan base-package="com.dprima.controller" />

        <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
            <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
            <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
            <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
        </bean> 
    ...
```

my **redirect.jsp**

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<% response.sendRedirect("index.php"); %>
```

my **index.jsp**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Spring 3</title>
</head>
<body>
    ${hello}
</body>
</html>
```

I have added all JARs including **jstl.jar** & **standard.jar** because I assume this will required for the **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/Config** error. However, it still displays HTTP 500 for the **http://localhost:8080/passion/index.php** and HTTP 404 for **http://localhost:8080/passion/**.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

JARs should be in WEB-INF/lib, not subdirectories.

If you're deploying on Tomcat, you might try putting those JSTL JARs in the Tomcat /lib so the server class loader can find them.

Comment: it works smoothly when i put jstl.jar at my Tomcat "lib" directory, thanks duffymo.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you must be use tomcat and your pom.xml is like:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

delete the scope node, or change "provided" to "compile"
then maven copy jstl-api-1.2.jar to the WEB-INF/lib.

then OK.

Comment: thank you for answering my question, maybe i forgot to tell you that im using ant when facing this problem. but now i prefer using maven.

Comment: scope- compile, helped me

Answer (score 0):

, Why do you redirect this page using?

```
<% response.sendRedirect("index.php"); %>
```

you can map index php as a welcome file. I did it the following way:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/index.php</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

and then:

```
 <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.php</welcome-file>
      </welcome-file-list>
```

it will show your index.dlp as index file.
Danny.

Comment: Hi Danny, thank you for your response, as i mentioned before, i've add jstl.jar & standard.jar under WEB-INF/lib/jstl11 is that any effect if i've added the jars here WEB-INF/lib/jstl11 not in WEB-INF/lib ?

Comment: Sorry I missed the last part. please see my updated suggestion. Hope it helps

Comment: Yes it makes a dereference you should put it in lib directory.

Comment: I'm using <% response.sendRedirect("index.php"); %> to redirect http://localhost:8080/passion to http://localhost:8080/passion/index.php , unfortunately i still got java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/Config error after change the web.xml as you suggested to me, i've changed the jstl.jar directory as you suggested too...

Comment: i've tried your last edited answer... still error... i guess, i'll keep trying danny, if you have another clue for my problem please tell me, i still Google it, thank you in advance...